# How can I block vulnerability scans when the hackers are spoofing Google-bots IP address?

Tags: php, security, ip, googlebot, spoofing

My WordPress server keeps getting knocked offline by hackers running vulnerability scans. When I check my logs I see thousands of lines like this: ( I replaced the domain name with ***'s)

```
/var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log-20210307:12682:[Mon Mar 01 03:41:14.012378 2021] [access_compat:error] [pid 20560] [client 66.249.66.223:59346] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/**********.com/account.php
```

There are thousands of these and they all happen at the same time like a DDOS attack. They try other urls too, it looks like a list of known plug-in vulnerabilities. Reverse IP lookup on 66.249.66.223 shows it is Google-bit but this is clearly not true so I can only assume they are spoofing the IP.

I am using CloudFlare and could put in a firewall rule to trigger blocking any IP that requested the url /account.php but then I will be blocking GoogleBot from crawling my site. I'm stumped.

Comment: If you limited this to requests for `/account.php`, then where’s the real damage? Probably not too much sense in the Google Bot trying to index _that_ page in the first place – assuming, that it will display the information of a logged-in user …?

Comment: @CBroe that is one of the hundreds of URI's they try (most of them are plug-in urls or other known security flawed files) - I can't block /wp-admin.php because that's how everyone logs in, "/account.php" is just one example. I actually did block account.php even though that file doesn't even exists.